# ImportError: path/to/_spatialite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_bind_int64

Tags: python, ubuntu, spatialite

I know, simmilar questions have been asked, but I didn't really find any help.

I used pip install pyspatialite to build the pyspatialite library.
Since this doesn't work, I had to build it manualy with:
python setup.py install

Therefore I first had to download the amalgamation for libspatialite and put this into
/build/pyspatialite/amalgamation  from this source: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-sources/

I also edited the /build/pyspatialite/src/connection.h file and removed 'int spatialite_init(int verbose);' because of duplication.

after all, I made it to build the whole library with:
python setup.py install

But now I get this python error:

```
from pyspatialite import dbapi2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/pythonPlayground/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pyspatialite._spatialite import *
ImportError: /home/user/pythonPlayground/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspatialite/_spatialite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_bind_int64
```

I read, this has something to do with the linked librarys for _spatialite.so file.
How can I fix this, or what did I miss?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: do you have sqlite3-devel package (or similar) installed?

Comment: yes libsqlite3-dev is installed